# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `bio` on serializer `ProfileSerializer`

Tags: django-rest-framework

i am trying to set up an api for user profile but i'm getting

"Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `bio` on serializer ProfileSerializer.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'bio'."

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(User, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    URL1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    URL2 = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("bio", "profile_pic", "URL1", "URL2")
```

View.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request):
    user = request.user

    try: 
        user_detail = user.id
    except item_detail.DoesNotExist: 
        return Response({'message': 'The Item does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    Profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(user_detail) 
    
    return Response(Profile_serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass an <**int**> instance to ProfileSerialzer instead of a profile instance.
Try in this way

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request):
    user = request.user

    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user)
    
    Profile_serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile) 
    
    return Response(Profile_serializer.data)
```